# add scroll bar to dynamically generated selection options

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, scrollbar

I have a div, which contains an empty select. When the page loads, the Javascript will dynamically add content to that select. But some will extend the width of the select tag. So I want a horizontal scroll bar. I tried to add

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

to the div's style, but it did not work since the contents were added through Javascript.

How can I add scroll bar in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Add your css inside the function of your javascript after you adding the content